# How does the yaaaw escrow program work for multiple NFTs?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, typescript

yaaaw is a solana dapp built on the basic escrow program to safely exchange tokens , they upgraded it to work with NFTs and solana and other tokens , you can deposit multiple NFTs in the same transaction , my question is : does they use multiple accounts to store those Mint addresses and amounts , or they are creating a single PDA and passing the mints with amount as VEC

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because yaw has since been sunset and the question never received any answers